# Internationalization R knitr Figure caption label

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I want to generate a Latex document with knitr, but it does not allow me to change the label for the figure into my language. The code:

````
```{r rstudio, echo = FALSE,  fig.cap = "RStudio IDE", fig.margin = T}
plot(pressure)
```
````

This generates:

[image]

However I want the caption label to read Figura: (portuguese) instead of Figure: . I added the variable `lang: pt-br`, which corrects for when I call it with `\@ref(fig:rstudio)`, but does not fixes the figure label.

- How to change the caption label in Rmarkdown?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can actually include LaTeX code directly within the Rmd file to alter the settings.

As [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993/122325) explains, names like "Figure" and "Contents" are stored in macros like `\figurename` and `\contentsname`. To change them, you have to change the definition of the respective macros using `\renewcommand` within your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
```

Here's a list of the "name macros" (and their default meaning) defined by the LaTeX standard classes `article`, `book`, and `report`:

- `\abstractname` [only `article`, `report`]: Abstract
- `\appendixname`: Appendix
- `\bibname` [only `book`, `report`]: Bibliography
- `\chaptername` [only `book`, `report`]: Chapter
- `\contentsname`: Contents
- `\figurename`: Figure
- `\indexname`: Index
- `\listfigurename`: List of Figures
- `\listtablename`: List of Tables
- `\partname`: Part
- `\refname` [only `article`]: References
- `\tablename`: Table

Here is a MWE for your scenario:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: default
---
\renewcommand{\figurename}{YOUR LABEL}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{TABLE LABEL}

```{r Table, echo =FALSE}
knitr::kable(iris[1:5,], caption = "A table")
```

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="Test Caption"}
plot(pressure)
```
````

### Alternative Approach

The fantastic package bookdown expands a lot on the basics of RMarkdown and knitr. One thing the package allows you to set internalisation, as explained [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/internationalization.html).

Comment: This works very well! Do you have an idea how to get rid of the space between the label and the number? \renewcommand{\figurename}{YOUR LABEL} will result in "YOUR LABEL 1" while I would like to have "YOUR LABEL1".