# Rmarkdown: Modify Figure X label to Figure SX in pdf or word output

Tags: latex, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to use Rmarkdown to automatically label Figure's caption, but instead of counting `Figure 1`, I want it to be `Figure S1`, i.e. just adding `S` there. [An example here](https://www.debugcn.com/en/article/11169989.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51945079/how-to-change-the-figure-caption-format-in-bookdown) suggests that this is not possible using pdf output.  Ok, I am fine with .doc file,  but still my figure caption is not print out? I wonder what could be wrong?

Minimal example for R markdown:

````
    ---
title: Supporting Information
subtitle: "Iron(I) etc"
author: "Some people here"
abstract: "Added the addresses here since there is no abstract in the SI"
output:
  word_document:
    fig_caption: yes
---

```{r, include=F}
library(captioner)

figS<- captioner(prefix = "Figure S", auto_space = TRUE, levels = 1, type = NULL,  infix = ".")

figS("Figure S1", "Single-crystal X-ray structure of some text (1)", display=FALSE)

```

```{r Xray, fig.cap=figS("This is my figure description"), echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

This prints correctly out `Figure S1`. But, now my actual figure description is missing?

[image]

My desired output is pdf, but if not, I can do with word. Thanks for suggestion how to fix this!

Comment: I edited my answer to remove the blank space between `S` and the number. So, instead of `Figure S 1` now we have `Figure S1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use some LaTeX commands under `header-includes:` in the YAML section, as follows:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure S}
  - \makeatletter
  - \def\fnum@figure{\figurename\thefigure}
  - \makeatother
---

```{r, fig.cap="This is my figure description", fig.height=3}
plot(pressure)
```

```{r, fig.cap="Another figure description", fig.height=3}
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Width)
```
````

[image]

(The argument `fig.height` in the R code chunks is not necessary; I used it only to get both plots in the same page and take the screenshot)

Comment: thank you so much @canovajsm! nice, easy and simple solution. I have struggled  with this for days! saved my day :)

Comment: The equivalent four lines also work for Tables