# Remove colon in figure caption using pandoc and bookdown in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

I am changing the font of a figure caption in my R Markdown and am using `bookdown` and pandoc to do so. My question is closely related to: [How to change the figure caption format in bookdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51945079/how-to-change-the-figure-caption-format-in-bookdown). I was able to get correct figure numbering and was able to alter the format of the "Figure 1" portion of the caption. However, I cannot figure out how to remove the colon in the output (i.e., "Figure 1:. ").

**Minimal Example**

Pandoc Function (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59301855/15293191))

```
function Image (img)
  img.caption[1] = pandoc.Strong(img.caption[1])
  img.caption[3] = pandoc.Strong(img.caption[3])
  img.caption[4] = pandoc.Strong(".  ")
  return img
end
```

To use `function Image` in the R Markdown, save the file as "figure_caption_patch.lua", which will be called in `pandoc_args` in the YAML metadata.

*R Markdown*

````
---
title: Hello World
author: "Somebody"
output:
  bookdown::word_document2:
    fig_caption: yes
    number_sections: FALSE
    pandoc_args: ["--lua-filter", "figure_caption_patch.lua"]

---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```    

# Test
Some text (Figure \@ref(fig:Xray)). Some text followed by a figure:

```{r Xray, fig.cap="Single-crystal X-ray structure of some text", echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

**Output**

> **Figure 1:.** This is a caption.

**Desired Output**

> **Figure 1.** This is a caption.

In the pandoc function, I tried to subset the string of `img.caption[3]`, but it did not work. I tried the following:

```
img.caption[3] = pandoc.Strong(string.sub(img.caption[3], 1, 1))
```

I know that if I was using R, then I could do something like:

```
a = c("words", "again")
substring(a, 1, 1)[1]

#output
[1] "w"
```

But unsure, how to do this with pandoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there was a change in `rmarkdown` which adds a colon by default. Also the reason why the answer in the linked post does not work anymore. For more on this and a solution see https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-change-the-figure-table-caption-style-in-bookdown/110397.

Besides the solution offered there you could achieve your desired result by replacing the colon by a dot. Adapting the lua filter provided by https://stackoverflow.com/a/59301855/12993861 this could done like so:

```
function Image (img)
  img.caption[1] = pandoc.Strong(img.caption[1])
  img.caption[3] = pandoc.Strong(pandoc.Str(string.gsub(img.caption[3].text, ":", ".")))
  return img
end
```

[image]