# How to change default name for table note in apa_table()?

Tags: r, papaja

I'm trying to write a .pdf report using `papaja` r package. It's not in English so I need to translate some fixed parts to Polish. I managed to translate figure and table name thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47173279/internationalization-r-knitr-figure-caption-label) question, using:

```latex
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Rysunek}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabela}
```

Yet I don't know how to translate table note from `apa_table()` from "Note." to "Adnotacja.". The workaround is to keep .tex file, find & replace and render outside RStudio. Is it possible to set it inside the RMarkdown file?

Comment: If you are interested in extending the language support in `papaja`, I'd be more than happy to include your translations, if you open a PR on the [localization function](https://github.com/crsh/papaja/blob/2572124f7cba193bbbaf02e6e5edcbcc0d3dfc8f/R/lookup_tables.R#L294).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of these words are defined in global options named `papaja.terms`, and you might even want to change more than just the note here to avoid the latex quick fixes all together. See the options here:

```r
> getOption("papaja.terms")

$author_note
[1] "Author note"

$abstract
[1] "Abstract"

$keywords
[1] "Keywords"

$word_count
[1] "Word count"

$table
[1] "Table"

$figure
[1] "Figure"

$note
[1] "Note"

$correspondence
[1] "Correspondence concerning this article should be addressed to "

$email
[1] "E-mail"
```

In order to change the language of the word corresponding to 'note'.

E.g.

```r
polish_terms <- getOption("papaja.terms")
polish_terms$note <- "Adnotacja"
options("papaja.terms" = polish_terms)
```