# Accessing language specific fixed names in papaja.terms

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, papaja

I am writing a APA-report in RStudio with rmarkdown and the papaja-package. Everything ist working fine except that I cannot change the names of "Figures", "Tables", "Keywords" etc in papaja.terms to the german denominations. I know that they are there and that the rmarkdown::metadata$lang needs to be changed to "german" so that the localize() function can switch the names.

BUT I just cannot find a way to change it. You cant do it in the console but if I do it in the YAML header with "lang: german or de-DE" I just get an error when knittin:

Error running filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2arm64/Resources/library/rmdfiltr/replace_ampersands.lua:

...-arm64/Resources/library/rmdfiltr/replace_ampersands.lua:13: attempt to index a nil value (field 'c')

stack traceback:

Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 83

What am I missing here? Is there a better easier way to do this or do I need to change the YAML-setting.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/72448539/17818921 works in the setup chunk. When checking with getOptions(papaja.terms) it shows the specified german names. But when the PDF is knitted the changes are not used in the document and only the english/default names are used. It shouldn't be necessary to specify new words anyway since they are already in the code.