# Papaja with Rmarkdown fails to knit when using YAML header with "lang:"

Tags: r-markdown, papaja, pandoc-citeproc

When using rmarkdown with the papaja package and using YAML header with "lang:", the knitting runs into an error:
rror running filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/rmdfiltr/replace_ampersands.lua:
...-arm64/Resources/library/rmdfiltr/replace_ampersands.lua:13: attempt to index a nil value (field 'c')
stack traceback:
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 83
Execution halted

[same behavior was already reported here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75906890/accessing-language-specific-fixed-names-in-papaja-terms)

I'm able to avoid this message, when I switch to biblatex citing:
papaja::apa6_pdf:
citation_package: biblatex
biblio-style      : "apa"

but then, the citing is not correct apa style anymore. At least when you have more than 2 authors to be cited for the first appearance in the text, this is shortened to et al. i.E. when it should be (Wiers, Gladwin, Hofmann,Salemink, & Ridderinkhof, 2013) it shows (Wiers et al.,2013) instead.

Any idea how to get around this? Tried already adding :
csl: apa-6th-edition.csl

But that didn't help either.

Comment: Have you tried removing `lang:` from the YAML front matter?